# How to auto deploy on remote tomcat by maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'd like to deploy a war project on a remote tomcat server on maven build. There seems to be a plugin `tomcat-maven-plugin` that is capable of this.

But I also have to start a batch script prior to deployment that stops some processes and shuts the tomcat server down safely. Is it also possible to execute such a remote script by maven just before the deployment?

Comment: What is it exactly you need to have done when redeploying?

Comment: You need to use Maven antrun plugin. Here is similar thread on this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668839/maven-and-exec-forking-a-process hope it helps

Comment: visit this link http://wiki.aiwsolutions.net/2014/02/20/deploy-web-application-to-remote-tomcat-7-server/

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you push a new Jar using the remote deployment feature of Tomcat, it will gracefully restart your container.

If you need to do more than that, this is probably not a solution for you.

When you say Batch script... does it means you are deploying on a Windows server?

Comment: Yes I have to deploy on a windows server

Comment: I would look at stuff like http://octopusdeploy.com/ then. Trying to embed a Jar/Tomcat into a NuGet package. But Windows is such a Diva for automation. Sorry.