# How do I run the maven exec plugin multiple times in a build

Tags: java, maven-3, selenium-grid, exec-maven-plugin

Below is the relevant part of my POM -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>StartHub</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-jar</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/lib/Hub/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar</argument>
                    <argument>-role</argument>
                    <argument>hub</argument>
                    <argument>-throwOnCapabilityNotPresent</argument>
                    <argument>false</argument>
                    <argument>-newSessionWaitTimeout</argument>
                    <argument>20000</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>StartNode</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-jar</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/lib/Node/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar</argument>
                    <argument>-hub</argument>
                    <argument>http://127.0.0.1:4444/register/grid</argument>
                    <argument>-port</argument>
                    <argument>5555</argument>
                    <argument>
                        Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=${basedir}/chromedriver.exe</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I was trying to use the exec plugin to execute a jar(selenium standalone server) in two configurations(hub and Node).

My issue is that the jar is executed only once in the configuration specified between the first pair of "execution" tags. I have searched extensively for a solution and the only thing I found was that the id's for different executions need to be different, which I rectified. I still can't seem to manage to run the jars twice even though I can run any one of them successfully if I comment out the execution of the other.

I should also mention that I'm running the project in Eclipse, so ideally what I would want to do is right-click on the POM.xml click on Run-as and select "Maven test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Maven executions issue but rather an issue related to what you are executing: a blocking process (the first server) which would stop the build listening for a node which would never get connected (because its execution won't start).

Changing your pom to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>StartHub</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-version</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>StartNode</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-version</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It would perfectly execute the two exec executions, printing twice the Java version. Note: the snippet is a copy and paste from your question, just replacing arguments of the `java` command to its `version` option.

---

What you are most probably looking for is to execute the two commands in background or at least in a non-blocking way in order to get the second executed, then proceed with the build (to execute some tests I presume).

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4668839/5606016) on how to achieve it: instead of using the `exec-maven-plugin`, use the `maven-antrun-plugin` to launch the two selenium commands.

---

As a further note, you should probably consider using the [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin) instead and execute integration tests, attaching the executions above to the `pre-integration-test` phase and stop them during the `post-integration-test` phase in order to properly clean them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have handled this using process builder, but its nice to know why it wasn't working and about the Antrun plugin. I am aware of the failsafe plugin, but I didn't go for it because there is nothing I need to do before and after the tests that I can't handle using the annotations provided by testNG. I would be interested in knowing if handling such tasks via Maven has any inherent advantage over doing it programmatically. But I guess that is a different question altogether!!
Once again thanks for your time!! I'm accepting this as the answer